# Django I can't pull data from database

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-views

Admin can change the web title,keywords or description. But it's not working rn. When i entry website everything is fine i don't have any error but informations didn't come from database.

This is my home/models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Setting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    fax = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    email = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    smptpserver = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    smptemail = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    smptpassword = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    smptport = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    icon = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    facebook = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    instagram = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    twitter = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    aboutus = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_map = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    references = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptade_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is my home/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import Setting
def index(request):
    setting=Setting.objects.all()
    context={'setting':setting}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

This is my home/temp/index.html

```
{% block title %} {{ setting.title }} {% endblock %}
{% block keywords %} {{ setting.keywords }} {% endblock %}
{% block description %} {{ setting.description }} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: `Setting.objects.all()` this will give a list of objects, not an object. You must iterate through this before accessing instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're returning a whole queryset, not a single item

```
setting=Setting.objects.all()
context={'setting':setting}
```

If you only ever have one `Setting` record, you could use `Setting.objects.first()` instead. If you have more than one you should use `Setting.objects.get(...)` to retrieve a single record.

You can see this for yourself if you examine the value of `setting` in the view before you return it (use a `breakpoint()` to look at the vars in the shell, or just print it out).

As long as you use `all()` the template will be expecting an iterable of objects for you to loop over - that iterable will not have properties like `keywords`, `description` etc.

Comment: I tried with `Setting.objects.get(pk=1)` but still not working :(

Comment: DoesNotExist at /
Setting matching query does not exist. error

Comment: And is the pk of the single record actually `1`? Double check this in admin ...